# Prevent WebSocket Request from adding default headers

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket

I'm writing a websocket client to connect to a server which I do not have the source code for (black box testing).

When I try to connect to the server with the following code, the default headers keep getting added to the request, and as a result it fails due to the specs of [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-11.3.1) only allowing a single `Sec-WebSocket-Key` to be used in the header.

```
socket_key = "Sec-WebSocket-Key: " + r.headers['Sec-WebSocket-Accept']

websocket.enableTrace(True)
ws = create_connection('wss://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket', headers=[socket_key])
```

However, this request is being sent instead:

```
--- request header ---
GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: example.com
Origin: http://example.com
Sec-WebSocket-Key: <Generated WebSocket Key>
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: <socket_key from above>
```

How can I prevent the first `Sec-WebSocket-Key` header from appearing, or replace its generated WebSocket key in the request with my own WebSocket key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in a dictionary instead of a list, for the `header` argument:

```py
my_header = { "Sec-WebSocket-Key" : "12345abcde" }
ws = websocket.create_connection("ws://127.0.0.1:8000/", header = my_header)
```

For this code, I see the following outbound request:

```
websocket:--- request header ---
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8000
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 12345abcde
```